# Finite entropy and finite moments

Tags: probability, statistics, entropy

This question is about when a discrete distribution has finite entropy because it has finite moments.

Let $X$ be a discrete random variable (which can be positive, negative, and/or zero unless stated otherwise), and let— $$H(X) = \sum_n -\mathbb{P}[X=n] \ln(\mathbb{P}[X=n]),$$ be the Shannon entropy of $X$.

It is known that:

- If $X$ is integer-valued and has a finite variance, then $H(X)$ is finite (Massey 1988).
- If $X$ is integer-valued, is 0 or greater, and has a finite mean, then $H(X)$ is finite (Rioul 2022).

It is also known that [a discrete distribution can have infinite Shannon entropy even if it's positive-valued](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4017267/does-any-probability-distribution-have-an-entropy-defined) (one example is some members of the zeta Dirichlet distribution); see also Devroye and Gravel 2020.

However, I believe that this is so because the infinite-entropy zeta Dirichlet distributions (I think) have an infinite $z$th moment for any real $z>0$.

Moreover, I believe that the Cauchy distribution has a finite entropy even though its mean is infinite because it does have a finite $z$th moment for some $z$ in $(0, 1)$, in fact for *every* $z$ in $(0, 1)$.

However, several questions remain on the relationship between finite entropy and finite moments.

### Questions

- If $X$ is supported on the whole set of integers and is such that $\mathbb{E}[X^2]$ is infinite but $\mathbb{E}[X^z]$ is finite for some $z$ in $[1, 2)$, then is $H(X)$ finite? If not, under what additional conditions is $H(X)$ finite?
- If $X$ is supported on the integers or some subset thereof, such that $\mathbb{E}[X]$ is infinite but $\mathbb{E}[X^z]$ is finite for *every* $z$ in $(0, 1)$, then is $H(X)$ finite? If not, under what additional conditions is $H(X)$ finite?
- If $X$ is supported on the integers or some subset thereof, such that $\mathbb{E}[X]$ is infinite but $\mathbb{E}[X^z]$ is finite for *some* $z$ in $(0, 1)$, then is $H(X)$ finite? If not, under what additional conditions is $H(X)$ finite?
- If $X$ is supported on the integers or some subset thereof, such that $\mathbb{E}[X^z]$ is infinite for every real $z > 0$, then is $H(X)$ infinite?

### Motivation

My motivation is to characterize the discrete distributions with finite entropy, since only finite-entropy distributions can be sampled in finite time on average (Knuth and Yao 1976).

### References

- O. Rioul, "Variations on a Theme by Massey," in IEEE Transactions on Information Theory, doi: 10.1109/TIT.2022.3141264.
- Massey, J.L., "On the entropy of integer-valued random variables", 1988.
- Devroye, L., Gravel, C., "[**Random variate generation using only finitely many unbiased, independently and identically distributed random bits**](https://arxiv.org/abs/1502.02539v6)", arXiv:1502.02539v6  [cs.IT], 2020.
- Knuth, Donald E. and Andrew Chi-Chih Yao. "The complexity of nonuniform random number generation", in *Algorithms and Complexity: New Directions and Recent Results*, 1976.

Comment: Thanks for the nice question! However, as explained [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/279344/1096797), the entropy of positive integer valued random variables can be infinite. Please edit the question to avoid confusion.

Comment: @Matija: I don't see how this question should be edited, but I have tried.

Comment: Can you please tell me what result exactly in Rioul 2022 you reference? The problem is that the assertion as you have written it is false.

Comment: @Matija: It turned out to be theorem 8, which also assumes a finite mean.  I have corrected this post.

Comment: That answers the 1st question. Seems the answer to the 3rd question is worth a publication, since this would (and I guess, will) extend the results by Rioul. I have a construction in mind to negatively answer the 4th question. However, as pointed out before, we have to work with $\mathbb E[|X|^z]$. Recall that $\mathbb E[X]$ is well-defined iff $\mathbb E[\max(0,X)]<\infty$ or $\mathbb E[-\min(0,X)]<\infty$, so $|\mathbb E[x]|<\infty$ iff $\mathbb E[|X|]<\infty$, i.e. we don't loose anything by working with the absolute, and it's always defined. If 2 out of 4 are okay, I'll write it down.

Comment: @Matija : Have you considered my questions further?

Answer (score 3):

I assume that $X$ takes non-negative integral values.

---

First, suppose that $E X^a<\infty$ for some $a>0$. Then for all $n\ge 0$, it holds either that
$$
p_n\log \frac{1}{p_n}\le n^a p_n
$$
or
$$
p_n\le e^{-n^a}.
$$
But in the latter case, we can also bound, say, $\log(1/p_n)\le \sqrt{p_n}$. So both upper bounds are summable, and we get $H(X)<\infty$.

---

Reciprocally, if we know that $E X^a=\infty$ for all $a>0$, there is not much we can say about $H(X)$. Consider for example $p_n=1/m^2$ if $n=e^m$ for some $m\ge 0$ and $p_n=0$ otherwise. You can check that $p_n$ satisfies the all-infinite-moments condition (in fact, the main term of the sum does not even converge to $0$), but
$$
\sum_{n\le e^m} p_n\log(1/p_n)=\sum_{k\le m} \frac{\log(k^2)}{k^2}.
$$
So $H(X)<\infty$.

Comment: Thank you for the response.  Can you answer for the case when $X$ can be negative as well as positive?  All along I intended the case when $X$ can be positive and/or negative, unless stated otherwise in the question, especially the case when $X$ can take any positive or negative integer.

Comment: @PeterO. - so what does the moment condition correspond to now? Should we put absolute values?

Comment: Only $z$th moments for any real $z > 0$, and the absolute values of the moments are taken (e.g., where I said "$\mathbb{E}[X^z] = \infty$", I meant "$\mathbb{E}[X^z]$ is infinite" or "$\mathbb{E}[X^z]$ is positive infinity or negative infinity").

Comment: @PeterO. - but this is not even defined if the exponent is not an integer

Comment: In that case, only one question remains to be asked: If $X$ is supported on _the whole set of integers_ and has a finite mean, then is $H(X)$ finite?

Comment: @PeterO. Then $X$ has a finite mean, the mean is well-defined, which means that $X^+$, $X^-$ have finite means. The answer suggests that $X^+$, $X^-$ have finite entropies, which immediately suggests that $X$ has a finite entropy.

Comment: @md5 If you use "either or", one of the inequalities should be strict. More importantly, I don't understand your $\log(1/p_n)\le\sqrt{p_n}$ bound. Say, $X$ is Bernoulli with $3/4$, so the choice of $a$ doesn't matter. For $n=0$ we have $p_0=1/4<1=e^{-0}$, but $\log(1/p_0)>1>1/2=\sqrt{p_0}$. Please correct the answer to avoid future confusion.